# parsing json response array in javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I have a json arry

```
{
    "result": "sucess",
    "senderids": [{
        "id": "2",
        "senderid": "powers",
        "status": "0",
        "type": "2",
        "availa": "0",
        "user": "admin"
    }, {
        "id": "3",
        "senderid": "powert",
        "status": "0",
        "type": "2",
        "availa": "0",
        "user": "admin"
    }, {
        "id": "4",
        "senderid": "powerd",
        "status": "0",
        "type": "2",
        "availa": "0",
        "user": "admin"
    }, {
        "id": "5",
        "senderid": "pavank",
        "status": "0",
        "type": "1",
        "user": "pavan"
    }]
}
```

Javascript:

```
var res = xhr.responseText;
var s = res.senderids;
for (i = 0; i < s.senderids.length; i++) {
    var contact = JSON.parse(s.senderids[i].senderid);
    alert(contact);
}
```

How i can parse this json array using `JSON.parse`. I have tried this code

thanks in advance

Comment: i have tried the following code                                                              var res = xhr.responseText;     
var s=res.senderids;
for(i=0;i<s.senderids.length;i++)
{
var contact = JSON.parse(s.senderids[i].senderid);
alert(contact)  
}

Comment: `var s = res.senderids;` this only will work after you've parsed `res`. `JSON.parse` in the loop is way too late :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var res = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
    var s = res.senderids;
    for (i = 0; i < s.senderids.length; i++) {
        var contact = s.senderids[i].senderid;
        alert(contact);
    }
```